# Drupal Commerce product display text input on specific option

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a Product Display that shows a group of products with color and size options. However, I want to show "Custom" as a color option, and if the user selects it, I want a text box to appear where they can input custom text. I can do a custom submit hook to handle the input no problem, but is there a "Drupal way" to add a text box on a certain product option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use drupal conditional field module , and then on a certain value configure your text field to be displayed .
[conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields)